# Start / stop systemd automount on a single mountpoint

Tags: systemd, automounting

Given a mountpoint (directory) name, how do I start / stop the `systemd` automounter only on that mountpoint?

I want a solution which works even if the mountpoint:

- is currently mounted
- has `[^0-9A-Za-z]` characters in the pathname

Comment: Isn't systemd.automount always set up per mount point via fstab option or unit file?

Comment: If you want to stop but not disable you can always look for the name of the unit (iirc hyphenated-mountpoint-path.automount) with `systemctl` and stop it.

Comment: @TomYan [stopping the `.automount` has unexpected behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390514/start-stop-systemd-automount-on-a-single-mountpoint?noredirect=1#comment696057_390521)

Comment: I am not sure why stopping the automount unit should also stop the mount unit (which is equivalent to unmount the mountpoint AFAIK)

Comment: Related: [Stopping an `.automount` without unmounting the currently mounted filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405597/143394)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390525/143394):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    {
        printf "Stop systemd automount at <mountpoint>\n" "${0##*/}"
        printf "Usage:  %s <mountpoint>\n" "${0##*/}"
    } >&2
    exit 1
fi

MOUNT=$1
sudo systemctl stop "$(systemd-escape -p --suffix=automount "$MOUNT")"
```

Answer (score 6):

IIRC this was added relatively recently, but it sounds like you might want to use `systemd-mount --umount WHERE`.  Making sure WHERE is passed correctly in the scripting language of your choice is your problem :).

Or you should be able to use the regular `umount` command.  systemd picks up unmounts using kernel events or something, so you won't end up with a misleading status on the corresponding `.automount` unit.

Comment: `systemd-umount` can be used to unmount a mount or automount point. It is the same as `systemd-mount --unmount`

Comment: @TomHale heh, I think I'd go for `systemd-mount -u` myself.

Comment: Yup, it's easy to miss the `u` in `umount`.

Comment: `Discovery only supported for block devices, don't know what to do.` Any tips?

Comment: That sounds bogus and bug-worthy.  The implicit `--discover` shouldn't apply to unmount.  "Or you should be able to use the regular `umount` command."

Comment: `umount -vt autofs /media/backup` has weird behaviour - somtimes it says `umount: /media/backup (systemd-1) unmounted` and sometimes `umount: /media/backup unmounted`. In the latter case, it actually *mounts* the mountpoint!

Comment: Since you mentioned it was bug-worthy, I raised it [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6756).

Comment: so, raising bugs where possible is good, but that's totally not the bug I referred to :).

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6758 "documented `systemd-umount WHERE` does not work"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example expressed in shell.

```
MOUNT="/media/backup"
MOUNT_UNIT="$(systemctl show --property=Id "$MOUNT" | sed -e s/^[^=]*=// )"
AUTOMOUNT_UNIT="$(echo "$MOUNT_UNIT" | sed -e s/[.]mount$/.automount/)"
systemctl stop "$AUTOMOUNT_UNIT"
```

To try and answer this question completely, you could instead use `systemd-escape` to generate the unit name, as described in the [answer to the linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390525/29483).

Comment: `media-backup.automount` will need to be stopped as well. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390522/143394) which hopes for a more generic way of converting a path into a unit file name.

Comment: @TomHale right.  So more like this.  What happens when you stop the automount unit, should the answer be editted to stop the mount unit as well?  If so, before or after stopping the automount?

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405597/143394) about stopping the `.automount` without unmounting the currently mounted filesystem.