# systemd: convert path to systemd unit name format

Tags: systemd

How do I convert arbitrary paths to `systemd` unit file name format?

For example, how would I convert a path like `/media/backup` to `media-backup` so I could stop the automounter via:

```
systemctl stop media-backup.automount
```

The solution should escape special characters.

Comment: Is there any list of those arbitrary paths or do you want to convert every path in the system? What have you tried to do ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use [`systemd-escape`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-escape.1.html) which is designed explicitly for this:

```
systemd-escape -p --suffix=automount /media/backup
```

`-p` specifies that you’re escaping a path, and handles `/`, `.` and `..` appropriately. Special characters are handled correctly too. Thus your command would become

```
systemctl stop "$(systemd-escape -p --suffix=automount /media/backup)"
```

The escaping rules are described in the [`systemd.unit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) manpage.

Comment: This should work perfectly. Given [`umount -l` is dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390056/143394), I'm surprised to see that [`systemd` lazy unmounts the mountpoint](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6754) with this command.